# WPF editable combobox slow typing

Tags: wpf, performance, combobox

I have a WPF combobox like this :

`<ComboBox x:Name="CustomerComboBox" IsEditable="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Relations.View}" 
              DisplayMemberPath="Model.sname" />`

If I click in the editable combo while the binding is in place (MVVM) to give it focus, and I then press and hold any key, I assume the combo will be filled with that key rather quickly, but it isn't.
If I remove the displaymemberpath and then do the same, then I have the expected behavior. Of course I really need the binding.

The performance penalty only shows when the combo has a lot of elements mine has 6000.

I cannot understand where this performance penalty is coming from. Is there any way to bypass this problem ?

Comment: I think you bind to a lazy loading data source, and when you typing, the search doing with fetch data from database,so data loading is slow, correct?

Comment: No the data is already loaded.

Comment: Are you automatically saving the data whenever you change it?  If so, the penalty may be there - resaving the data for each letter you type in.

Comment: That is not it either. This problem can be reproduced really easy in a small test project.

Comment: What happens is that each time a charackter is typed in the textbox that belongs to the combo a textchanged event is processed by the combobox event code. In that code a binding expression is created based on the displaymemberpath and evaluated for each and every entry in the combobox. The reason it does so is that it tries to perform completion and calculate the selected index for the text the user has typed in the combo at that time. I was able to reverse engineer this using .NET reflector

Comment: How many items are present in the list?

Comment: ten thousand and you see the slowlyness. In the post above i mentioned 6000. It is used as a customer combobox. I am loading all customers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code solves the issues by creating a specialised combobox that basically caches all binding results. I created it by looking at the orginal source code of the combobox and itemscontrol using .NET reflector.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Reflection;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Collections;

namespace ICeTechControlLibrary
{
    public class FastEditComboBox : ComboBox
    {
        //PARTS
        private TextBox _TextBoxPart = null;

        //DEPENDENCY PROPERTIES
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty
            = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(AutoCompleteTextBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Journal | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, new PropertyChangedCallback(FastEditComboBox.OnTextChanged)));

        private List<string> _CompletionStrings = new List<string>();
        private int _textBoxSelectionStart;
        private bool _updatingText;
        private bool _updatingSelectedItem;
        private static Dictionary<TextBox, FastEditComboBox> _TextBoxDictionary = new Dictionary<TextBox,FastEditComboBox>();

        static FastEditComboBox()
        {
            EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(TextBox), TextBox.TextChangedEvent, new TextChangedEventHandler(FastEditComboBox.OnTextChanged));
            EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(TextBox), TextBox.SelectionChangedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(FastEditComboBox.OnSelectionChanged));
        }

        public string Text
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)base.GetValue(TextProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                base.SetValue(TextProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();
            _TextBoxPart = base.GetTemplateChild("PART_EditableTextBox") as TextBox;
            if (!_TextBoxDictionary.ContainsKey(_TextBoxPart)) _TextBoxDictionary.Add(_TextBoxPart, this);
        }

        private void OnTextBoxSelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this._textBoxSelectionStart = this._TextBoxPart.SelectionStart;
        }

        private void OnTextBoxTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsEditable)
            {
                TextUpdated(_TextBoxPart.Text, true);
            }
        }

        private void TextUpdated(string newText, bool textBoxUpdated)
        {
            if (!_updatingText && !_updatingSelectedItem)
            {
                try
                {
                    _updatingText = true;
                    if (base.IsTextSearchEnabled)
                    {
                        int num = FindMatchingPrefix(newText);
                        if (num >= 0)
                        {
                            if (textBoxUpdated)
                            {
                                int selectionStart = this._TextBoxPart.SelectionStart;
                                if ((selectionStart == newText.Length) && (selectionStart > this._textBoxSelectionStart))
                                {
                                    string primaryTextFromItem = _CompletionStrings[num];
                                    this._TextBoxPart.Text = primaryTextFromItem;
                                    this._TextBoxPart.SelectionStart = newText.Length;
                                    this._TextBoxPart.SelectionLength = primaryTextFromItem.Length - newText.Length;
                                    newText = primaryTextFromItem;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                string b = _CompletionStrings[num];
                                if (!string.Equals(newText, b, StringComparison.CurrentCulture))
                                {
                                    num = -1;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (num != base.SelectedIndex)
                        {
                            SelectedIndex = num;
                        }
                    }
                    if (textBoxUpdated)
                    {
                        Text = newText;
                    }
                    else if (_TextBoxPart != null)
                    {
                        _TextBoxPart.Text = newText;
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    _updatingText = false;
                }
            }
        }

        internal void SelectedItemUpdated()
        {
            try
            {
                this._updatingSelectedItem = true;
                if (!this._updatingText)
                {
                    string primaryTextFromItem = GetPrimaryTextFromItem(SelectedItem);
                    Text = primaryTextFromItem;
                }
                this.Update();
            }
            finally
            {
                this._updatingSelectedItem = false;
            }
        }

        private void Update()
        {
            if (this.IsEditable)
            {
                this.UpdateEditableTextBox();
            }
            else
            {
                //this.UpdateSelectionBoxItem();
            }
        }

        private void UpdateEditableTextBox()
        {
            if (!_updatingText)
            {
                try
                {
                    this._updatingText = true;
                    string text = this.Text;
                    if ((this._TextBoxPart != null) && (this._TextBoxPart.Text != text))
                    {
                        this._TextBoxPart.Text = text;
                        this._TextBoxPart.SelectAll();
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    this._updatingText = false;
                }
            }
        }

        protected override void OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.RaiseEvent(e);
            this.SelectedItemUpdated();
            if (this.IsDropDownOpen)
            {
                object Item = SelectedItem;
                if (Item != null)
                {
                    base.OnSelectionChanged(e);
                }
                //object internalSelectedItem = base.InternalSelectedItem;
                //if (internalSelectedItem != null)
                //{
                //    base.NavigateToItem(internalSelectedItem, ItemsControl.ItemNavigateArgs.Empty);
                //}
            }
        }

        int FindMatchingPrefix(string s)
        {
            int index = _CompletionStrings.BinarySearch(s, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            if (index >= 0) return index;
            index = ~index;
            string p = _CompletionStrings[index];
            if (p.StartsWith(s, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) return index;
            return -1;
        }

        protected override void OnDisplayMemberPathChanged(string oldDisplayMemberPath, string newDisplayMemberPath)
        {
            FillCompletionStrings();
        }

        protected override void OnItemsChanged(System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnItemsChanged(e);
            switch (e.Action)
            {
                case System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                    AddCompletionStrings(e.NewItems);
                    break;
                case System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                    RemoveCompletionStrings(e.OldItems);
                    break;
                case System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
                    FillCompletionStrings();
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void FillCompletionStrings()
        {
            _CompletionStrings.Clear();
            AddCompletionStrings(Items);
        }

        private void RemoveCompletionStrings(IList items)
        {
            foreach (object o in items)
            {
                RemoveCompletionStringForItem(o);
            }
        }

        private void AddCompletionStrings(IList items)
        {
            foreach (object o in items)
            {
                AddCompletionStringForItem(o);
            }
        }

        private void AddCompletionStringForItem(object item)
        {
            Binding binding = new Binding(DisplayMemberPath);
            TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
            tb.DataContext = item;
            tb.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, binding);
            string s = tb.Text;
            int index = _CompletionStrings.BinarySearch(s, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            if (index < 0)
            {
                _CompletionStrings.Insert(~index, s);
            }
            else
            {
                _CompletionStrings.Insert(index, s);
            }
        }

        private string GetPrimaryTextFromItem(object item)
        {
            Binding binding = new Binding(DisplayMemberPath);
            TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
            tb.DataContext = item;
            tb.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, binding);
            string s = tb.Text;
            return s;
        }

        private void RemoveCompletionStringForItem(object item)
        {
            Binding binding = new Binding(DisplayMemberPath);
            TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
            tb.DataContext = item;
            tb.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, binding);
            string s = tb.Text;
            int index = _CompletionStrings.BinarySearch(s, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            if (index >= 0) _CompletionStrings.RemoveAt(index);
        }

        private static void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox tb = e.Source as TextBox;
            if (tb.Name == "PART_EditableTextBox")
            {
                if (_TextBoxDictionary.ContainsKey(tb))
                {
                    FastEditComboBox combo = _TextBoxDictionary[tb];
                    combo.OnTextBoxTextChanged(sender, e);
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            }
        }

        private static void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox tb = e.Source as TextBox;
            if (tb.Name == "PART_EditableTextBox")
            {
                if (_TextBoxDictionary.ContainsKey(tb))
                {
                    FastEditComboBox combo = _TextBoxDictionary[tb];
                    combo.OnTextBoxSelectionChanged(sender, e);
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            }
        }

        private static void OnTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            FastEditComboBox actb = (FastEditComboBox)d;
            actb.TextUpdated((string)e.NewValue, false);
        }
    }
}
```

selecting the very first element clears the selection with this implementation.
so still some bugs here